# Dask Concatenate a Series of Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I have a Dask Series of Pandas DataFrames. I would like to use `dask.dataframe.multi.concat` to convert this into a Dask DataFrame. However the `dask.dataframe.multi.concat` always requires a list of DataFrames.

I could perform a `compute` on the Dask series of Pandas DataFrames to get a Pandas series of DataFrames, at which point I could turn that into a list. But I think it would be better not to call `compute` and instead directly acquire the Dask DataFrame from the Dask Series of Pandas DataFrames.

What would the best way to do this? Here's my code that produces the series of dataframes

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
import operator
import numpy as np
import math
import itertools

def apportion_pcts(pcts, total):
    """Apportion an integer by percentages
    Uses the largest remainder method
    """
    if (sum(pcts) != 100):
        raise ValueError('Percentages must add up to 100')
    proportions = [total * (pct / 100) for pct in pcts]
    apportions = [math.floor(p) for p in proportions]
    remainder = total - sum(apportions)
    remainders = [(i, p - math.floor(p)) for (i, p) in enumerate(proportions)]
    remainders.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    for (i, _) in itertools.cycle(remainders):
        if remainder == 0:
            break
        else:
            apportions[i] += 1
            remainder -= 1
    return apportions


# images_df = dd.read_csv('./tests/data/classification/images.csv')
images_df = pd.DataFrame({"image_id": [0,1,2,3,4,5], "image_class_id": [0,1,1,3,3,5]})
images_df = dd.from_pandas(images_df, npartitions=1)

output_ratio = [80, 20]

def partition_class (partition):
    size = len(partition)
    proportions = apportion_pcts(output_ratio, size)
    slices = []
    start = 0
    for proportion in proportions:
        s = slice(start, start + proportion)
        slices.append(partition.iloc[s, :])
        start = start+proportion
    slicess = pd.Series(slices)
    return slicess

partitioned_schema = dd.utils.make_meta(
    [(0, object), (1, object)], pd.Index([], name='image_class_id'))
partitioned_df = images_df.groupby('image_class_id')
partitioned_df = partitioned_df.apply(partition_class, meta=partitioned_schema)
```

In the `partitioned_df`, we can get `partitioned_df[0]` or `partitioned_df[1]` to get a series of dataframe objects.

---

Here is an example of the CSV file:

```
image_id,image_width,image_height,image_path,image_class_id
0,224,224,tmp/data/image_matrices/0.npy,5
1,224,224,tmp/data/image_matrices/1.npy,0
2,224,224,tmp/data/image_matrices/2.npy,4
3,224,224,tmp/data/image_matrices/3.npy,1
4,224,224,tmp/data/image_matrices/4.npy,9
5,224,224,tmp/data/image_matrices/5.npy,2
6,224,224,tmp/data/image_matrices/6.npy,1
7,224,224,tmp/data/image_matrices/7.npy,3
8,224,224,tmp/data/image_matrices/8.npy,1
9,224,224,tmp/data/image_matrices/9.npy,4
```

I tried to do a reduction afterwards, but this doesn't quite make sense due to a proxy `foo` string.

```
def zip_partitions(s):
    r = []
    for c in s.columns:
        l = s[c].tolist()
        r.append(pd.concat(l))
    return pd.Series(r)

output_df = partitioned_df.reduction(
    chunk=zip_partitions
)
```

The proxy list that I'm attempting to concat is `['foo', 'foo']`. What is this phase for? To discover how to do the task? But then certain operations don't work. I'm wondering if it's because I'm operating over objects that I'm getting these strings.

Comment: I encourage you to produce a minimal example.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .  That will make it easier for people to help.  See also https://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports

Comment: Since it appears that one cannot concatenate a series of dataframes. I'm thinking instead of using a custom aggregation to zip merge each series of dataframes together.

Comment: @MRocklin I have created the example that you can run. Zipping up column-wise is turning out challenging as well because either I'm using groupby-agg, which then gives me SeriesGroupBy objects that I don't know what to do with, or if I use `reduction` afterwards, I get this proxy string `foo` that doesn't work for concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out an answer by applying the reduction at the very end to "zip" up each dataframe into a series of dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
import operator
import numpy as np
import math
import itertools


def apportion_pcts(pcts, total):
    """Apportion an integer by percentages
    Uses the largest remainder method
    """
    if (sum(pcts) != 100):
        raise ValueError('Percentages must add up to 100')
    proportions = [total * (pct / 100) for pct in pcts]
    apportions = [math.floor(p) for p in proportions]
    remainder = total - sum(apportions)
    remainders = [(i, p - math.floor(p)) for (i, p) in enumerate(proportions)]
    remainders.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    for (i, _) in itertools.cycle(remainders):
        if remainder == 0:
            break
        else:
            apportions[i] += 1
            remainder -= 1
    return apportions


images_df = dd.read_csv('./tests/data/classification/images.csv', blocksize=1024)

output_ratio = [80, 20]


def partition_class(group_df, ratio):
    proportions = apportion_pcts(ratio, len(group_df))
    partitions = []
    start = 0
    for proportion in proportions:
        s = slice(start, start + proportion)
        partitions.append(group_df.iloc[s, :])
        start += proportion
    return pd.Series(partitions)


partitioned_schema = dd.utils.make_meta(
    [(i, object) for i in range(len(output_ratio))],
    pd.Index([], name='image_class_id'))

partitioned_df = images_df.groupby('image_class_id')
partitioned_df = partitioned_df.apply(
    partition_class, meta=partitioned_schema, ratio=output_ratio)


def zip_partitions(partitions_df):
    partitions = []
    for i in partitions_df.columns:
        partitions.append(pd.concat(partitions_df[i].tolist()))
    return pd.Series(partitions)


zipped_schema = dd.utils.make_meta((None, object))

partitioned_ds = partitioned_df.reduction(
    chunk=zip_partitions, meta=zipped_schema)
```

I think it should be possible to combine both the reduction and apply to a single custom aggregation to represent a map reduce operation.

However I could not figure out how to do such a thing with the custom aggregation since it uses a series groupby.

[image: Visualized Graph]